# How to run Vim Diff without enter in interctive mode?

Tags: vimdiff

I really like the `vimdiff` / `vim -d` , it's awesome.

But I need to see the vimdiff result without enter in the interactive mode.

Show the result colored , scrolling all differences and exit. Behave like a `diff -y`, side-by-side, but with the benefits of the colored and diff configuration from vim.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish that Vim's interactive mode is blocking?

Comment: @8bittree , not sure what you mean with blocking,the idea is just scroll the diff result and back to the prompt, just like `diff`command but with vim output format.

Comment: I mean why are you trying to avoid entering interactive mode? Usually the reason to avoid interactive mode is to do something with a pipeline, but you also want color which has a tendency to make pipeline processing very difficult.

Comment: If you just want coloring, there are several syntax highlighting pagers

Answer (score 1):

Before saving a file, I frequently verify changes before saving using:

`:w !diff - %     (diff <memory copy>  <original file>`

Quickly see changes in a simple diff style  without changing the file.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This doesn't appear to help answer the question of non-interactive vimdiff

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having the differences above each other as opposed to side-by-side, you can try this:

```
git diff --no-index FILE1 FILE2
```

Comment: Thank you @Kostas, but the great advantage of the vimdiff is the side-by-side + colored diffs. Is exactly what I want to keep.